# Change only one textbox instead of all

Tags: jquery, textbox

I am trying to replace password textboxes with regular textboxes once the password has been entered. This code works only if the very first password textbox is not empty but then it also performs the code on every password textbox.

```
if ($('input[type=password]').val() != "") {
                    $('input[type=password]').hide(); 
                    $('input[class=showPswd]').show(); 
                }
```

I thought something like this would work but it is not.

```
if ($('input[type=password]').val() != "") {
                        $(this).find('input[type=password]').hide(); 
                        $(this).find('input[class=showPswd]').show(); 
                    }
```

How do I get the code to look at each password textbox and replace only that textbox when it is empty?

Thanks

EDIT: This is the general layout. There are more rows that are almost identical.

```
                <td class="style1">
                    QA :</td>
                <td class="style2">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server">                   
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>

                <td style="vertical-align:middle">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" textmode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox21" runat="server" style="display:none;" class="showPswd" value="Accepted"></asp:TextBox>

                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text=""
                    ></asp:Label>
                    </td>                
            </tr>
```

Comment: Show us the markup on where the password field `<input type="password"..` and the `<input class="showPswd".. ` fields are located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make use of [**`each()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function , to do the operation on each textbox having type password like as below

```
    $('input[type=password]').each(
    function ()
    {
    if ($(this).val() != "")  
     { 
              $(this).hide(); 

              //just replace this line as you need not sure what is does 
              //$(this).find('input[class=showPswd]').show();
     } 

  });
```

Comment: I think this worked for hiding the password textbox. The textbox i'm wanting to show is right after the password textbox. How can I get it to show?

Comment: I think I got it. $(this).next().show(); worked. Thanks for your help